# invalid Column name Practice_PK

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity

I have the below code where am working on an ASp.net MVC application

```
 public class Element
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Primary Key
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
public int Pk { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Practice_PK")]
    [Display(Name = "Practices")]

    public Practice Practice { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Practices")]
    public int Practice_PK { get; set; }
```

}

```
Database
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Elements] (
    [Pk]                     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Practice_PK]            INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Elements_dbo.Practices_Practice_PK] FOREIGN KEY ([Practice_PK]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Practices] ([PK]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Practice_PK]
    ON [dbo].[Elements]([Practice_PK] ASC);
```

I am getting the Error "Invalid Column name Practice_PK" everytime i try to create, Edit a page. I know this has been addressed many times but the error itself is so ambiguous i dont know how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved my issue .Basically the 'Practice_PK' returning the error was for another variable ElementType   (Not included the code above )  that is of the type ElementType  that should have had a Practice_PK varaible but did not